# What "appropriate source of randomness" in php random_int means?

Tags: php, random

I was writing some PHP code when I came to an warning in my coding saying "Unhandled Exception" pointing to the use of `random_int` in some part of my algorithm. I wasn't aware that `random_int` could throw an exception so I made a research and [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php#refsect1-function.random-int-errors) said that the exception occurs when "(...) an appropriate source of randomness cannot be found(...)".

My question is: what does exactly "appropriate source of randomness" is? I tried to google it but I didn't find any answers.

If this is to much of an open-ended question, please, consider only the scope of the `random_int` function.

To provide more information, I'm using PHP 7.4.3 (NTS) in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. The message that I'm receiving is "Unhandled exception" and nothing else but the line and column where the exception is unhandled.

Comment: Computers are deterministic and they cannot really generate random numbers. For that reason, operating systems offer mechanisms to generate random-enough seeds for pseudo-random functions like `random_int()`. Your PHP set up doesn't seem to have access to one. Maybe you can edit the question and provide the **exact** error message, together with information about your OS and PHP setup.

Comment: Did you not read the section above the one you quote? `The sources of randomness used for this function are as follows: ...... keep reading`

Comment: Thanks @ÁlvaroGonzález, I edited the quesiton :)

And thank you for the advise too, @RiggsFolly. Actually that section didn't come to my attention, when I readed the docs I jumped straight to the `Errors/Exceptions` part

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ubuntu should have both `getrandom()` and `/dev/urandom`, so why would it raise that exception?

Comment: Copy and paste the full text of the actual exception into your question.

Comment: Hi @Barmar My comment was just answering the question of what was considered appropriate sources of randomness. I hoped that the OP would then be able to examine there system for one of those sources or work out why there system didnt have one. Justhelping them towards a solution, not providing one I am afraid as I dont have one

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I've updated the question. The only text in the error was "Unhandled exception"